# How to parse json where key name is integer number

Tags: java, json, gson

I need to parse json like this:

```
{
"response": {
    "70": [326707130, 320565529, 218874712, 195318591, 272944693, 136909660, 384774802, 9486342, 5663588, 245478751, 437283231],
    "75": [205268343, 307729010, 272944693, 384774802, 312530843, 220948861, 270477243]
}
}
```

Im using GSON, and i dont know what to do, because i can`t name the variable in Java like this:

```
public int[] 70;
```

Comment: Note: the keys in your example aren't numbers. They're strings that happens to contain only digits.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `@SerializedName` or a `Map`.

Easiest is a `Map`:

```
class Root {
    Map<String, List<Integer>> response;
}
```

The keys can be integers too:

```
class Root {
    Map<Integer, List<Integer>> response;
}
```

But if you prefer defined fields, use `@SerializedName`:

```
class Root {
    Response response;
}

class Response {
    @SerializedName("70")
    List<Integer> listA;

    @SerializedName("75")
    List<Integer> listB;
}
```

In all cases you read the JSON using:

```
Root root = gson.fromJson(in, Root.class);
```